# Can we read heart beat data from wear os using raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, wear-os, android-sensors

I have purchased a Ticwatch which is running Android wear OS. I want to read the heart beart data from the device over bluetooth using raspberry pi. I found no resources to do so. But I found a tutorial to do so using Polar H7. Link below:

https://github.com/danielfppps/hbpimon

But the same thing is not doing anything with Ticwatch wear OS.

Can anyone even tell me if this is even possible ?

Comment: Might be a better question for the raspberry pi stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself - it's quite likely that nobody has, it's a real corner case - but I have no doubt that it's doable.

Getting the heart rate data on Wear is pretty easy; there's an API to do just that. Here's a SO Q&A with some basic code to do so: [How to read Heart rate from Android Wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760344)

Transferring that data to your RasPi is going to be more work, but it's still eminently possible. Both devices support a full Bluetooth stack, but there's no simple API for this, so you'll have to build this piece more-or-less from scratch. On the Android side, a good starting point is Google's Bluetooth Chat sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

In summary: Anything's possible. Many things are difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own app on Wear OS. Thanks for all help.